# How do I update a user profile with entity_metadata_wrapper()?

Tags: 7, entities

I got an error while updating user profile data such as name,password and email. I am using `entity_metadata_wrapper()` for processing update.

> exception 'EntityMetadataWrapperException' with message 'Unknown data property original.' in C:\xampp\htdocs\phone_bay\sites\all\modules\entity\includes\entity.wrapper.inc:335\nStack trace:\n#0

This is my code.

```
require './includes/password.inc';
function commerce_services_user_update($uid, $data, $flatten_fields) {
    $user = user_load($uid);
    $wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('user', $user);
    dpm($wrapper->value());

    $name = $data['name'];
    $password = $data['password'];
    $email = $data['email'];

    if ($name != null) {
        $wrapper -> name  = $name;
    }
    if($password != null){
        $wrapper -> pass = user_hash_password($password);
    }
    if ($email != null) {
        $wrapper -> mail = $email;
    }

    try {       
        user_save($wrapper);
        $message = "successessfully update!";
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $message = "not success! -> ". $e;
    }

    $reply = (array('status' => $status,'message' => $message));
    return $reply;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using an entity wrapper, you must use `$entity->save` to save the updated user object. In your case, use `$wrapper->save`.

[`user_save()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_save/7) can be used when the user entity is loaded using [`user_load()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_load/7).

Comment: Not ok yet after changing code to $wrapper -> save();  exception still occurs. (exception 'EntityMetadataWrapperException' with message 'Invalid data value given. Be sure it matches the required data type and format.' in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\phone_bay\\sites\\all\\modules\\entity\\includes\\entity.wrapper.inc:737\nStack trace:\n#0)

Comment: Have you given correct values in the user object? Because mail validation also happens here.

Answer (score 0):

The user entity needs to be also saved. The full code for changing the username and the email address is then the following one.

```php
$wrapper->name->set('Jean louis');
$wrapper->mail->set('mail@mail.com');
$wrapper->save();
```